# Prove that every integer n≥12 is the sum of two composites.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

Prove that any natural number greater than 
or equal to 12 is the sum of two composite numbers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How would you approach this problem?

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where did this problem come from? Why $12$?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If $n$ is even, then $n$ is the sum of $4$, which is composite, and $n-4$, which is even (a multiple of 2), hence composite, provided $n>6$.

If $n$ is odd, then $n$ is the sum of $9$, which is composite, and $n-9$, which is even (a multiple of 2), hence composite, provided $n>11.$